# UCA + Natural Sorting

Tags: php, sorting, unicode, natural-sort

I recently learnt that PHP already supports the [Unicode Collation Algorithm via the intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/collator.create.php):

```
$array = array
(
    'al', 'be',
    'Alpha', 'Beta',
    'Álpha', 'Àlpha', 'Älpha',
    'かたかな',
    'img10.png', 'img12.png',
    'img1.png', 'img2.png',
);

if (extension_loaded('intl') === true)
{
    collator_asort(collator_create('root'), $array);
}

Array
(
    [0] => al
    [2] => Alpha
    [4] => Álpha
    [5] => Àlpha
    [6] => Älpha
    [1] => be
    [3] => Beta
    [11] => img1.png
    [9] => img10.png
    [8] => img12.png
    [10] => img2.png
    [7] => かたかな
)
```

As you can see this seems to work perfectly, even with mixed case strings! The only drawback I've encountered so far is that there is no support for [natural sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) and I'm wondering what would be the best way to work around that, so that I can merge the best of the two worlds.

I've tried to specify the `Collator::SORT_NUMERIC` sort flag but the result is way messier:

```
collator_asort(collator_create('root'), $array, Collator::SORT_NUMERIC);

Array
(
    [8] => img12.png
    [7] => かたかな
    [9] => img10.png
    [10] => img2.png
    [11] => img1.png
    [6] => Älpha
    [5] => Àlpha
    [1] => be
    [2] => Alpha
    [3] => Beta
    [4] => Álpha
    [0] => al
)
```

However, if I run the same test with only the `img*.png` values I get the ideal output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```

Can anyone think of a way to preserve the Unicode sorting while adding natural sorting capabilities?

Comment: @dan04: Care to expand on that?

Comment: With lexicographical order, fixed-width hex numbers will sort correctly.  E.g.: 80, 8A, 90.  With "natural sort", you get 8A, 80, 90 instead.

Comment: @dan04: Yeah, but... Unrelated, no? If I had to choose, I'd rather have natural decimal sorting than natural sorting in any other base. Nonetheless, the works perfectly comment was referring to the UCA not natural sorting, since that clearly isn't implemented in `intl`.

Comment: You **do** have to choose.  My point is that if you implement "natural sort", it will **break** some sorts that worked just fine under lexicographical order.  Not just hex, but any mixed letter/digit identifier like license plate numbers or product/customer IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging a little more in the documentation I've found the solution:

```
if (extension_loaded('intl') === true)
{
    if (is_object($collator = collator_create('root')) === true)
    {
        $collator->setAttribute(Collator::NUMERIC_COLLATION, Collator::ON);
        $collator->asort($array);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => al
    [3] => Alpha
    [5] => Álpha
    [6] => Àlpha
    [7] => Älpha
    [1] => be
    [4] => Beta
    [10] => img1.png
    [11] => img2.png
    [8] => img10.png
    [9] => img12.png
    [2] => かたかな
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is trivially done.  You simply preprocess the list to zero-pad numbers.  For example, using [my *ucsort* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/ucsort), which supports the UCA, on this list of filenames:

```
% cat /tmp/numfiles
img4.png
img1.png
img2.png
img12.png
img21.png
img10.png
img20.png
img3.png
img22.png
```

will produce the desired output by using the [Unicode::Collate module’s](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3A%3ACollate) `--preprocess` hook to transform runs of digits into zero-padded ones:

```
% ucsort --preprocess='s/(\d+)/sprintf "%020d", $1/ge' /tmp/numfiles
img1.png
img2.png
img3.png
img4.png
img10.png
img12.png
img20.png
img21.png
img22.png
```

Looking at the PHP documentation you cite, it does not appear that that PHP library supports the full UCA tailoring possibilities that the Perl [Unicode::Collate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3A%3ACollate) module supports.  In fact, it looks more like Perl’s [Unicode::Collate::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3A%3ACollate%3A%3ALocale) module, except that the PHP library code does not seem to support the inherited collation options that the Perl code does.

I suppose that if all else fails, you could call Perl code to do what needs done.

Comment: Thanks. I can think of a way this could be implemented in PHP, with 2 arrays, `uasort()`, `collator_compare()` and `preg_replace()` with the eval modifier but seems so inefficient... =(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer of @tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056586/uca-natural-sorting/5057169#5057169) I've came up with this:

```
function sortIntl($array, $natural = true)
{
    $data = $array;

    if ($natural === true)
    {
        $data = preg_replace_callback('~([0-9]+)~', 'natsortIntl', $data);
    }

    collator_asort(collator_create('root'), $data);

    return array_intersect_key($array, $data);
}

function natsortIntl($number)
{
    return sprintf('%020d', $number);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 100
    [2] => al
    [3] => be
    [4] => Alpha
    [5] => Beta
    [6] => Álpha
    [7] => Àlpha
    [8] => Älpha
    [9] => かたかな
    [10] => img1.png
    [11] => img2.png
    [12] => img10.png
    [13] => img20.png
)
```

Still hoping for a better solution though.

Comment: PS: `array_intersect_key` produces unexpected results as can be seen on index 9, as all keys of the original array are also lost.